# How to get my geolocation in bash

Tags: api, bash, geolocation

I am looking for a good geolocation api to use from bash. I want this call to return at the very minimum the name of the city I am in, and the state.

I imagine that there must be some site I can curl, or some scripting language that has a package that works. The machine does not have a GPS, but it does use wireless internet most of the time if that is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was looking at this problem again recently and found [`whereami`](http://github.com/victor/whereami), a geolocation bash script for Mac OS X Snow Leopard, which takes advantage of Core Location.  This will tend to be much more precise than IP geolocation, and it works well in my tests.

Comment: That is just sexy. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Doesn't seem to build any more according to their instructions.

Comment: Same here, there is a pull requests that adds support for Swift 2, unfortunately Swift 3 is default in Xcode 8.

Comment: I tried whereami out as I was in Starbucks. The result is not accurate at all.

Answer (score 8):

Since [whereami](http://github.com/victor/whereami) is not (officially) available for Swift 2 and Swift 3, I digged a bit deeper and found [locateme](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/locateme/) what does its job on OSX 10.12.4:

[image: Screenshot of LocateMe]
Its asks for permission the first time, and then it works without any additional interaction. Also, the `format` parameter is nice:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[geolocate-cli](http://code.google.com/p/geolocate-cli/) is still in alpha but should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping the first Google hit result for "geoip" seems to work easily enough.

```
$ curl http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_my_ip |
> awk '/<table>/{RS=RS RS}/tblProduct1/'
```

I haven't checked their EULA to see if using their service this way is okay, but they do also provide GeoIP libraries for [C](http://www.maxmind.com/app/c), [Perl](http://www.maxmind.com/app/perl), [Python](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python), etc. with a "[lite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)" database that you can distribute (with [conditions](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/LICENSE.txt)).

Comment: Well, I'm in Cambridge MA yet maxmind puts me in Boston (close, but not the same), and hostip.info puts me in... Reston, VA, etc. :)  Not surprising since probably more than half the info still comes from `whois`.

Comment: Cool. I'm trying to think now of a good way to grep out just the city, region and country.

Comment: This method gave me a more accurate result than the program "whereami", but it is still far from where I really am. Plus, it requires internet connection. I am quite surprise that there seem not to be a gps locator in my laptop that tells me where I really am.

Answer (score 1):

If your platform is a *nixlike that supports `network-manager`, you can use this script:
`` curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/browserlocation/json?browser=firefox&key=AIzaSyDBgL8fm9bD8RLShATOLI1xKmFcZ4ieMkM&sensor=true" --data-urlencode "`nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,SIGNAL dev wifi list |perl -ne "if(s/^(.+?)\s+(..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+(.+?)\s*$/&wifi=mac:\2|ssid:\1|ss:\3/g){print;}"`" ``
Check out [How to create a script to query Google Browserlocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972546/how-to-create-a-script-to-query-google-browserlocation/30986056) for more details.

Notice that there's some limit to this service. It was working fine, at first, but now I get `"status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"`. I don't know what the limit is because I can only seem to find geocoding references, but if anyone knows, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Wireless internet meaning WiFi, CDMA2k, UMTS, EDGE... ? And your carrier?  Not that it matters.

Really.  I'd start investing in a GPS dongle.

Comment: just good ol 802.11g. I shouldn't need a gps if my browser can get my location without one.

Comment: I assume this is for yourself -- a mobile computer? :) You can get *a* location without GPS, never guaranteed to be the right one (GeoIP services can place you in a completely different state just because the ISP is registered there in `whois`.)