# How to create a script to query Google Browserlocation

Tags: json, google-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to get geolocation data from Google's Browser location API. I found [JSON, CURL and Google's geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433901/json-curl-and-googles-geolocation), and have it working as far as list of access points in range, but my limited cli-fu won't let me parse this into something I can send to Google.

So far, I have

```
nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,SIGNAL  dev wifi list
SSID             BSSID              SIGNAL 
ElisaKoti73      00:0C:C3:7F:7E:64  66     
Kanala           00:1E:AB:56:84:3F  65     
TW-EAV510v236E3  00:1E:AB:09:36:E4  44     
WLAN-AP          00:1E:AB:04:C5:C5  32     
meduusan verkko  00:1E:AB:54:C4:E0  25     
Koti_E8BC        EE:43:F6:99:E8:BC  22     
Inteno_E1        00:22:07:13:6A:E0  19
```

What I now want to turn that into is something like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/browserlocation/json?browser=firefox&sensor=true&
wifi=mac:00:0C:C3:7F:7E:64|ssid:ElisaKoti73|ss:66&
```

**Edit:** adapting from the answer by @hotmultimedia, I got to

```
curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/browserlocation/json?browser=firefox&sensor=true&" --data-urlencode "`nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,SIGNAL dev wifi list |perl -ne "if(s/^(.+?)\s+(..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+(.+?)\s*$/&wifi=mac:\2|ssid:\1|ss:\3&/g){print;}"`"
```

Now this works, but the accuracy is way off: `"accuracy" : 11178`. Bafflingly, if I copy-paste the same address in my browser, the returned JSON is perfectly fine with an accuracy of `"accuracy" : 52`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can accomplish this transformation using a (slightly non-optimal :)) Perl oneliner:

```
perl -ne "if(s/^(.+?)\s+(..:..:..:..:..:..)\s+(.+?)\s*$/https:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/browserlocation\/json?browser=firefox&sensor=true&wifi=mac:\2|ssid:\1|ss:\3&\n/g){print;}"
```